# How to use user profiles without login?

Tags: django, django-views

I have function in view:

```
def my_function(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'get_id' in request.POST:
            try:
                object = MyModel.objects.get(pk=int(request.POST['get_id']))
                return HttpResponse(str(object.id))
            except:
                pass
    return HttpResponse('Error')
```

and I want to use `@login_required` decorator - this function required authorization. But how to external system (not user - other script) authorize in my system? Systems exchange data with each other.

How to do it? I want use Django user auth but I don't want send username and pass in plaintext.

Comment: This might give you a headstart: http://code.google.com/p/django-pgpauth/ - you could use public-key/private key authorization. you might also want to look at restful apps like tastypie

Comment: What is the problem with sending it in plain text via https? You do it even for banking, c'mon.